# How to Stop a Recurring Event

Tags: org-mode

Is there a way to stop a Recurring Event in Org-Mode such as:

`TODO Blabla bla :SCHEDULED: <2019-07-05 +1w>`

I know I can go delete `+1w` , but then that's not good for my reference when I check the calendar and such.

Answer (score 2):

To indicate that you have completed the **current repetition** of a repeating task, use `C-c C-t`: this updates the properties and logs for the task, and sets it up for the next repeat.

To indicate that you have completed a repeating task **forever** (i.e., it no longer repeats), use `C-- 1 C-c C-t`. This marks the task as done, and removes the repeater flag from the timestamp. Your logging data remains, so you have your permanent record of your past activity on this task.

Comment: Hi Tyler, so every single time I try typing C-t it changes the order of my letters... 
eg. ** TODO reading :DEADLINE: <2019-05-25 Sat 11:00 +1w>
it becomes: ** TODO readnig :DEADLINE: <2019-05-25 Sat 11:00 +1w>
It will not let me finish the command. Any idea where I am going wrong?  (I am using C as Ctrl on the left and holding while I press t , I am familiar with Emacs (to a point, not an expert) and Emacs' commands)

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. `C-t` transposes characters, as you discovered. I meant to type `C-c C-t`

Comment: Ya, I kinda thought, but wasn't sure.  This didn't work for me either... It says already set to TODO... maybe the problem is that I have some config in .emacs that creates this issue.  I tried stopping it now by Archiving ```C-c C-x a``` this also seems to be doing the trick